# Unity keeps deleting the google-play-libs folder in plugins and not working

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I recently installed Unity 5.3.3 on a new computer, and I have set up Google Play Games Services. However, it does not automatically import the google-play-libs folder into assets>plugins>android.

To build successfully, I have to manually import the library and then build, but whenever I close and open Unity again, it keeps getting deleted and I have to continuously import it before every build.

Does anyone know how to fix the issue? I am using the 0.9.31a version of the plugin. One thing to note is that I get the error: Cannot find candidate artifact for com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0+
I read to fix it I must get the Android Support Repository in the SDK manager, but in mine it is not there, I only have Android Support Library.

Also, signing in with google does not work on the app itself.
I get the ADB logcat error:

```
I/GamesNativeSDK( 8741): Auth operation started: SIGN IN
I/GamesNativeSDK( 8741): Connecting to Google Play...
E/GamesNativeSDK( 8741): Not authorizing: no client.
I/Unity   ( 8741): AuthState == Unauthenticated calling auth callbacks with fail
ure
I/Unity   ( 8741):
I/Unity   ( 8741): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDe
bugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)
I/Unity   ( 8741):
I/Unity   ( 8741): Error sign in
I/Unity   ( 8741):
I/Unity   ( 8741): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDe
bugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)
I/Unity   ( 8741):
```

@Clayton Wilkinson Please Help!

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: is this a pc or a mac?  which windows?

Comment: It's a laptop pc running Windows Home Premium. I imported the project from my old pc running Vista so I had to change the Keystore location. I am wondering if I need to upload a new APK to the developer console which I am trying now. @JoeBlow

Comment: same problem with you, my os is mac